# Get system-default labels from QMessageBox standard buttons

Tags: pyqt, label, default-value, qmessagebox

I want to show the text from the 'Yes' and the 'No' button in the informative text of a `QMessageBox`, but I don't see how I can get these labels from the buttons.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

msgbox = QMessageBox()
msgbox.setStandardButtons(msgbox.Yes | msgbox.No)

info_text = "Click '{yes}' to confirm. Click '{no}' to abort."
msgbox.setInformativeText(info_text)

if msgbox.exec_() == msgbox.Yes:
    print("Confirmed")
else:
    print("Aborted")
```

By calling `setStandardButtons`, the button order and the button labels will be set to the default for the current operating system and the current language setting. How can I obtain these defaults so that I can use them for the slots in the string `info_text`?

I thought about using the `buttons` attribute from the `QMessageBox` object, which is a list of `QPushButton` objects. I can read the labels from there, but I don't see how I could determine whether the first element in the list is the `Yes` or the `No` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I was being stupid: along side the `buttons` attribute, there is also the `button()` method, which takes as its argument the button type that I want to retrieve. I can then use `text()` to get the label. Finally, the hotkey marker `&` has to be stripped from the label:

```py
info_text = "Click '{yes}' to confirm. Click '{no}' to abort.".format(
    yes=msgbox.button(msgbox.Yes).text().replace("&", ""), 
    no=msgbox.button(msgbox.No).text().replace("&", ""))

msgbox.setInformativeText(info_text)
```